# Ruby Program : Trailing zeros in the nth Power of a numbers factorial

Tags: c++, ruby

I am trying to port C++ code to Ruby.
Running the script gives me an "execution Timed Out" error.

This is the Ruby code:

```
t = gets.to_i
t.times do
    a = gets.to_i
    b = gets.to_i
    c = 0
    j = 5
    until j <= a do
      j*5
      c += a/j
    end 
    puts c*b
end
```

This is the C++ code:

```
#include<iostream>

main()
{
  long t, a, b, i = 0, j, c; 
  std::cin >> t;
  for( ; i < t ; i++)
  {
    std::cin >> a >> b;
    c = 0;
    for( j = 5 ; j <= a ; j *= 5) 
      c += a/j;
    std::cout << c * b << '\n';
  }
}
```

My input is:

```
2
100
10
5
4
```

Any my output is:

```
240
4
```

There are two test-cases:

1. The number of zeroes trailing in `(100!)^10`
2. The number of zeroes trailing in `(5!)^4`

Comment: You need to state a question. Also, an example with expected output would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: watch out for indentation problems and your loops are  inside one another in the ruby program as compared to the C++ one. Your program works fine with the input 1 10 20. But other ones, it is going for a toss.

Comment: you aren't assigning `j*5` back to `j` in the ruby example

Comment: Please pay a lot more attention to whitespace and how you format your code, your code is very difficult to read as it is.

Comment: @Vasif: in c++, the loops are nested as well.

Comment: Why did you tag your question `ruby-on-rails` (again)? There's nothing related to rails in it.

Comment: Also, I tried to edit the code in c++ for a better style. It is not really inviting to go through. Looks like there are pending edits and my edit did not go through. Can you please edit the c++ code with a decent style. One statement per line and your choice of spaces per indent.

Comment: Well thats done now

Comment: I agree that `(5!^4)` has `4` trailing zeros, but `(100!)^10` doesn't have `24`, it has [`240` trailing zeros](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(100!)%5E10). Or do I miss something?

Comment: @spickermann Sorry did a typing mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write the calculation in the Ruby like this:

```
a = 100
b = 10
((1..a).inject(:*)**b).to_s[/0*$/].size
#=> 240
```

Where `(1..a).inject(:*)` calculates `a!`, `**b` is the exponential function, `to_s` translates the number into a string, `[/0*$/]` extracts all trailing zeros und `size` counts them...